# Find an example of a simple graph with at least two cycles, max vertex degree $3$ and exactly $2022$ spanning trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The task is to find a graph with maximum vertex degree equal to $3$, at least two cycles and EXACTLY $2022$ spanning trees.

I've considered a graph with two vertices $u$ and $v$ where there is an edge $uv$. The vertex $v$ will be a vertex of degree $3$ and there will be two cycles connected to it, one with $6$ vertices and another one with $337$ vertices, which should gives us $6\times 337=2022$ spanning trees.

Could that be one of the possible solutions?

Comment: As you described it, $v$ has degree $5$. Rather, let $u$ be part of a $6$-cycle, let $v$ be part of a $337$-cycle, and connect the cycles with the edge $uv$.